# Permission issues while doing ssh setup in Cygwin

Tags: shell, permissions, cygwin

I'm trying to setup ssh-host in Cygwin and am getting the below error:

```
*** Warning: The permissions on the directory /var are not correct.
*** Warning: They must match the regexp d..x..x..[xt]
*** ERROR: Problem with /var directory. Exiting.
```

As of now, the `/var` directory has the below permissions.

```
$ ls -ld /var
drws--Srwx+ 1 Prashant Prashant 0 Mar 11 22:29 /var
```

How do I set d..x..x..[xt] permissions for `/var`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cygwin, it's not possible to change group permissions unless the group is `Users` or `Root`. Refer to *['chmod' cannot change group permission on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091972)*.

You won't be able to change the group permission until you change var's group owner to `Users`, so the best solution is:

```
chown :Users /var
chmod 757 /var
chmod ug-s /var
chmod +t /var
```

The last step of setting sticky bit is not really necessary though.

Comment: This isn't working. Same error. :(

Comment: what are the permissions now?

Comment: Here you go : drwx---rwx

Comment: do `chmod 757 /var` then `chmod ug-s /var` and then `chmod +t /var`

Comment: Same error :( Permissions are drwx---rwt now. It needs something like d..x..x..[xt]

Comment: strange the group permission are not chaning at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21867/discussion-between-miline-and-prashant1988).

Comment: As stated originally - the last step of setting +t is not neccessary

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you first need to add Cygwin to Windows' environment variables.

Do so by right clicking on computer and select *Properties*, 
then choose *Advanced system settings* and under the *Advanced* tab choose 
*Environment Variables*.

Locate "Path" under *System variables* and add ";C:\Cygwin\bin" with the semicolon at the end of it.

After you have done that run Cygwin as administrator and do as Miline suggested. 
It worked for me, so I hope it will work for others.